# replacement of my detailViewController in UISplitView crashes on rotating my app Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisplitviewcontroller, ipad, screen-rotation

I have a SplitViewController App with 2 initial controllers:

- leftViewController  (master)
- rightViewController (detail)

my rightViewController (detail) has the delegate of the splitViewController for presenting a button which shows/hides my menu (master)

my leftViewController (master) is a menu application, when I select any element of the menú I trigger a segue connected to my master and it replaces my detailViewController for the selected element of menu

when I do that and if I try to rotate my iPhone for hide menu my app crashes and says:

```
*** -[rightViewController respondsToSelector:]: message sent to deallocated instance
```

I guess it is because my splitViewController wants to communicate with its delegate, its old rightViewController, but it is gone, it has been replaced on my view,

maybe I need whether:

reasign my delegate to my new viewController (detail)
or
 remove delegate of my rightViewController and assign it then to my newViewController

also tried this in my new viewController:

```
@interface newViewController ()<UISplitViewControllerDelegate>

@end

@implementation newViewController 


- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    UISplitViewController *splitViewController = (UISplitViewController *)self.view.window.rootViewController;
    UINavigationController *navigationController = [splitViewController.viewControllers lastObject];
    splitViewController.delegate = (id)navigationController.topViewController;
}
...
@end
```

but still not working... I get the same message

how do I fix this???

thanks in advance

**EDIT:** add my segue code for helping to answer my question

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"viewSceneAgenda"]) {

        [segue.destinationViewController setTitle:@"Citas"];
        [segue.destinationViewController setUserIDElement:UID_CUS];
        [segue.destinationViewController setOverallAppointments:overallDates];

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please show the Segue code?

Comment: let me see going to add the code to my original post

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe you have to pass your delegate as you said to your newViewController... why don't you add this in your leftViewController (master)...

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{

    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showNewViewControllerScene"]) {

        UISplitViewController *splitViewController = (UISplitViewController *)self.view.window.rootViewController;
        splitViewController.delegate = segue.destinationViewController;

    }
}
```

just replace the segue identifier (showNewViewControllerScene) to match with yours on your storyboard

Comment: wow it works great, but I'm going to complement your answer let me put this!!! thank you

Answer (score 1):

Gonna complement Jesus Answer

Since I'm working with several segues, all of them must have the delegate of my UISplitView, also since iPhone doesn't support splitviews, I added a condition for assigning the delegate just if the user is running this app on any iPad

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{


    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice].model hasPrefix:@"iPad"]) {
        UISplitViewController *splitViewController = (UISplitViewController *)self.view.window.rootViewController;
        splitViewController.delegate = segue.destinationViewController;
    }

    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"viewSceneAgenda"]) {

        [segue.destinationViewController setTitle:@"Citas"];
        [segue.destinationViewController setUserIDElement:UID_CUS];
        [segue.destinationViewController setOverallAppointments:overallDates];

    }
}
```